# Name property missing in activity.from object in messageReaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am testing an MS Teams bot and have implemented an `onReactionsAdded` event like below.

```js
this.onReactionsAdded(async (context, next) => {
    var name=context.activity.from.name;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But the name property and value are missing

```json
  reactionsAdded: [ { type: 'laugh' } ],
  type: 'messageReaction',
  timestamp: 2021-03-31T12:26:50.115Z,
  id: '161719353xxx',
  channelId: 'msteams',
  serviceUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/',
  from: {
    id: '29:1lejmc96kXSbnIvqlxxxxxxxxx27Sm_-XNA-CWdIrI_OxL5xBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    aadObjectId: '59a26b60-1ca9-4cf0-a4e8-xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
```

The activity.from in `onMessage` contains the Name

```js
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
    var name=context.activity.from.name;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

```json
{
  text: 'fds',
  textFormat: 'plain',
  type: 'message',
  timestamp: 2021-03-31T12:25:37.809Z,
  localTimestamp: 2021-03-31T12:25:37.809Z,
  id: '1617fds794',
  channelId: 'msteams',
  serviceUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/',
  from: {
    id: '29:ccccccxxxxlZUuykg027Sm_-XNA-CWdIrI_OxfxxxxzD6AUmRJ1F8D5E96nw',
    name: '<Some name>',
    aadObjectId: '59a26b60-1ca9-4cf0-a4e8-xxxx'
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question.

Comment: Why is the "Name" property missing in the messageReaction response?

Comment: @InnovateIt - I don't know. That sounds like a bug. Why not report it to Teams instead of Stack Overflow? Though I'm wondering about something... it looks like the two activities in your question are coming from two different users. Is that the case, and could that account for the difference? Have you looked at a message activity and a message reaction activity from the same user? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @InnovateIt: It seems name is not expected in messageReaction. See the reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#schema-example-a-user-likes-a-message.  Id and aadObjectId is only given in response

Comment: @InnovateIt - Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

As @subba-reddi-tummuru writes, the response does not contain the name property according to the documentation